# How to add or remove a js file in head

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have 3 language: `en`, `tc`, `sc`, I want to achieve the below condition

1) When the current is `en`, add `en.js` to head and remove js file `tc.js` and `sc.js` in `head`

2) When the current is `tc`, add `tc.js` to head and remove js file `sc.js` and `en.js` in `head`

3) When the current is `sc`, add `sc.js` to head and remove js file `tc.js` and `en.js` in `head`

Can someone advise how to do that in jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a quick function that would load a script dynamically based on a language parameter.

```
addLanguageScript = function(lang) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
        script = document.createElement('script');

    script.type = 'text/javascript'
    script.src = lang + '.js'
    head.appendChild(script);
};

addLanguageScript('en');
```

To remove the files you can do something like in jQuery, but keep in mind if the scripts
where loaded they probably would have already had some effect.

```
$("script[src='en.js']").remove()
```

Comment: good solution it works without any external js used. thanks buddy

Answer (score 3):

Once the `document` is loaded, you cannot do it dynamically. But there's a script [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), which is a JavaScript file and module loader.

> It is optimized for in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments, like Rhino and Node. Using a modular script loader like RequireJS will improve the speed and quality of your code.

It has a good support to [use it with jQuery](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html). You may also want to load code on the fly, after page load. Check out the above link and it would surely target your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Why removing files in first place? If they were in page head it means they were already executed.

With Yesnope JS-module loader the solution will be like:

```
yepnope({
  test : lang=="en",
  yep : ['en.js']
});
```

http://yepnopejs.com/

BTW, this module-loader is used in Modernizr.

Answer (score 1):

[add and remove dynamically files in head section](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml)

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
```

Call Function:

```
loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js") //dynamically load and add this .js file
loadjscssfile("javascript.php", "js") //dynamically load "javascript.php" as a JavaScript file
loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css") ////dynamically load and add this .css file
```

for remove:

```
 $('head script[src*="en.js"]').remove();  // for removing dynamically     
  $('head script[src*="en.js"]').append();   // for append dynamically
```